# Creating a vector of random strings with conditions in R

Tags: r

The problem is :

Create a vector of 50 random names, each made of 5 letters,out of which only the first is capital.  The first, third and fifthletters are consonants and the second and fourth are vowels.

How can i do this?

Comment: can you please your code.  Does it have any length constraint

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `letters` and `LETTERS` which are built in constants in R, then define vowels as `c(1, 5, 9, 15, 21)`, which is the subset to select or remove. Use `sample` to get 50 of each with replacement, and `paste` them together:

```r
set.seed(69)
vowels <- c(1, 5, 9, 15, 21)
paste0( sample(LETTERS[-vowels], 50, TRUE),
        sample(letters[vowels], 50, TRUE),
        sample(letters[-vowels], 50, TRUE),
        sample(letters[vowels], 50, TRUE),
        sample(letters[-vowels], 50, TRUE))
#>  [1] "Valif" "Cirer" "Tuniw" "Kimil" "Qehoc" "Jemif" "Senoy" "Jazic" "Hihuy"
#> [10] "Cezor" "Fuzic" "Menas" "Covay" "Rupov" "Xanij" "Pujur" "Qimin" "Dunop"
#> [19] "Xokez" "Zacox" "Muhac" "Yitab" "Gojob" "Dedah" "Nepan" "Dinel" "Ceyaw"
#> [28] "Foxiv" "Fiven" "Zotob" "Bezug" "Pusod" "Jawad" "Suluq" "Zubic" "Minax"
#> [37] "Gowex" "Debec" "Xaqut" "Duvov" "Lalal" "Zavuv" "Xobuk" "Zugil" "Gibac"
#> [46] "Yocan" "Voyuh" "Nigeh" "Yuqew" "Humup"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just using a for loop to sample the built in vectors LETTERS and letters with conditional subsetting to subset to vowels and consonants

```
namesList <- list()

for(i in 1:50){

  namesList[[i]] <- paste(c(sample(LETTERS[!(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 1),
  sample(letters[(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 1),
   sample(letters[!(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 1),
  sample(letters[(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 1),
  sample(letters[!(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 1)), collapse = "")
}

namesVec <- unlist(namesList)
```

Or in a vectorised fashion (which is better)

```
paste(
  sample(LETTERS[!(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 50, replace = TRUE),
  sample(letters[(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 50, replace = TRUE),
  sample(letters[!(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 50, replace = TRUE),
  sample(letters[(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 50, replace = TRUE),
  sample(letters[!(LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U"))], 50, replace = TRUE), 
sep = "")
```

Comment: You could reduce the typing by defining `vowels <- LETTERS %in% c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")`

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to make an unnecessary object and each line of sampling was done by copy paste so not that much more typing :)